# How does an electromagnetic wave (or any other wave) move in space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, visible-light, waves, speed-of-light, classical-electrodynamics

Does light wave has a "force" which acts to move it, such as in case of material, and if not, what makes it move?

Comment: Why do you think light wave requires a force? Uniform motion requires no force and accelerated motion requires a force- these are Newtonian concepts. The motion of electromagnetic waves cannot be understood from Newtonian mechanics. You require Maxwell's equations.

Comment: But it is not the case in a material, I hoped that I had established this in my answer to the other question

Comment: you must go back to the definitions of force and the essential mechanics of waves, even if it is a skim read. There is no fruitful physics to be learnt from asking about light as oppose to other waves unless you have at least an appreciation of classical electrodynamics, let alone quantum mechanics

Comment: Thanx, really useful , I ll start these topic first, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Light is classically described by [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations), and it is [electromagnetic waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) , electric and magnetic fields varying in space that "move" the beam of light.

[image]

> The electromagnetic waves that compose electromagnetic radiation can be imagined as a self-propagating transverse oscillating wave of electric and magnetic fields. This diagram shows a plane linearly polarized EMR wave propagating from left to right (X axis). The electric field is in a vertical plane (Z axis) and the magnetic field in a horizontal plane (Y axis). The electric and magnetic fields in EMR waves are always in phase and at 90 degrees to each other.

At the microscopic quantum mechanical level , light is built up  out of zillions of photons, elementary particles, so no "force" is needed to explain the motion other than the momentum carried by the particles, which is the same as the energy in units where $c=1$, $E=h\nu$ where $\nu$ is the frequency of the classical wave that the photons build up..

Comment: I  am curious about the negative votes. I like being corrected if I am off and/or not clear.